# WIN32 - Last user to login

Tags: winapi, authentication, local-security-authority

Is there a reliably way to determine the last user name to login to the system? I've looked at LsaEnumerateLogonSessions() and LsaGetLogonSessionData() however they require elevation on Vista and later (which I'm keen to avoid). WMI has the same problem (presumably it's just calling Lsa behind the scenes).

I've also looked at "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser" in HKLM, but in testing that's unreliable and doesn't get updated.

I'm really only interested in console logons, rather than Fast User Switching or TS logons.

I've read various articles, but have yet to come up with a good solution.

Comment: XY problem.  Y is "I've got a hard time breaking through the logon security layers".  What is X?

Comment: I'm not trying to break through the security layers. I'm trying to find out if there's a way I can make my application run without requiring elevation.Not sure how finding out the username of the last user to login (and only the username) is much of a security risk, especially if an application is already running?

Comment: I think more info about your app and why the problem arose would be helpful.  Based  on the above, it's hard to imagine why knowing who logged in last will help your app do anything very sensible.

Comment: It's an inventory application and reports system information back to a central location. At the moment, all the information (serial numbers, device information etc) does not require elevation. It's executed by a service remotely using WMI to copy the file and run it. 

As well as knowing the computer details, it's useful to know who logged into it last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use [Audit Logon events](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742436.aspx) - this requires your service to have a user access right to see the Security log, but not be a full Administrator.

Eventid 528 indicates who logged on, you'd have to find the most recent instance of this.

Comment: Thanks. That's looking like my only answer, I'll do that and fall back to the registry if auditing isn't enabled. Frustrating, when every other platform other than windows lets you get that information without elevated access.